# NSPopUpButton of type pull Down , when i click on some menu item ,title of popup is not getting changed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton

Problem:

1. Take an instance of `NSPopupButton` of type Pull down.
2. Add few menu items to the pop up.
3. Run the code.
4. Select any menu item in the popup

   - Title of popup button is not getting changed.
   - I need to show the selected item as title of Popup same as Normal behaviour of `NSPopupButton` but with the type pull down.
   - Also Need to add an item as same name as title.

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ManagingPopUpItems.html),

> Unlike popup lists, the title of a popup button displaying a pulldown list is not based on the currently selected item and thus remains fixed unless you change using the cell’s setTitle: method.

If you want the selected item to be shown as title, the easiest way is to use a popup instead of pulldown. Or call `setTitle:` every time you change the selection.

Comment: Actually i need to make UI look like pullDown with the same behaviour as popup.

Comment: use `setTitle:` as mentioned in the documentation.